# Why does axios.get(url).data not work? (axios GET requests and property accessors; JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, properties, get

I have an async function that is requesting an object with a name and id property. I understand that you can't return `await axios.get(url).data.name` without getting kicked into the catch statement.

My question though is what is the reason that it doesn't work?

```
async function getConstellationNameById(id) {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/constellations/${id}`;

  try {
    return await axios.get(url).data.name;
  } catch (error) {
    throw `Constellation with id of ${id} could not be found.`;
  }

}
```

If I store the GET request in a variable instead and then use dot notation to access the name property it works:

```
try {    
    //return axios.get(url).data.name;
    const constellation = await axios.get(url);
    return constellation.data.name;
  }
```

Is it because dot notation has a timing to it? Therefore, while the GET request is in the event queue, the `.data.name` portion is considered sync code and fails to get anything? I had thought since it's being executed all in one line, property accessors would execute along with the GET request?

Or is it because of another reason?

I also thought you could only access a Promise object's properties within `.then()` and `.catch()` statements; is that not the case?

Apologize in advance if I'm misusing any terminology as I'm still learning! Just really want to make sure I understand the reasoning before continuing.

Comment: You just need parentheses, `(await axios.get(url)).data.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` has higher precedence than `await`, so your code is equivalent to:

```
return await (axios.get(url).data.name);
```

so `axios.get(url).data.name` would need to be a Promise. But the promise that you want to await for is returned by `axios.get(url)`. Add parentheses to force the proper grouping:

```
return (await axios.get(url)).data.name;
```

Comment: I see now, that helps a lot! With your latter formatting, would I even need to use await at that point? I just read that using await when returning a promise isn't usually needed, but maybe that doesn't apply here.

Comment: If you don't use `await` you have to use `.then()` to get the value that the promise resolves to. `return axios.get(url).then(x => x.data.name)`. But if you do this, you shouldn't declare `getConstellationNameById()` to be `async, either, because this returns a promise explicitly, and you don't want to wrap it in another promise.